# Error with connection of the additional module

Tags: react-native

Recently, the project had to add the function of streaming video. The video is produced via rtsp link.

Found the module I need:

react-native-vlc-player
https://github.com/ekreative/react-native-vlc-player

Created a new React Native project for testing.

And in the end get the exact same error:

Invariant Violation: requireenativecomponent: "RCTVLCPlayer" was not found in the UIManager.

Maybe I have something set wrong or are doing wrong.

Can someone advise me specifically on this module ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this package doesn't link properly. And this is not a trusted npm package and i think you should try another trusted npm package like
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vlc-player.